# paragraph rendering difference in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a paragraph that displays differently in chrome and firefox. In chrome I see that styles are applied by the user agent.

```
p {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

I tried to override these styles, but still no effect on the rendering. Is there a way the difference can be negated. So that they render the same way in both the browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/hozefa/hM4Rx/

Computed markp in chrome

```
color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
display: block;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 95px;
line-height: 19px;
margin-bottom: 13px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 3px;
text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
width: 526px
```

Computed markup in FF

```
font-family Arial,​Helvetica,​sans-serif
font-size   14px
color   #666666
line-height 19px
margin-top  3px
margin-right    0px
margin-bottom   13px
margin-left 0px
text-shadow #FFFFFF 0px 1px 0px
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) to `override` the browsers default styles.

[Example using Eric Meyer’s reset](http://jsfiddle.net/hM4Rx/1/)

Or you can try using `!important`.

Or even modifying those styles:

```
p{
    -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Bad Practice to use !important and not needed in this case

Comment: @Matto if the OP has a style that has a style that effects the `<p>`, then how to override it except usint `!important` with keeping those style. It's not a bad practice if you know what are you doing.

Comment: He just needs to set the style for p in his css. No need to add the !important tag. If you properly code your css in order no need to use this tag. The second part of you answer is correct, but no need to use !important (I didn't down vote you, just pointing this out)

Comment: @Matto "If you properly code your css in order no need to use this tag". Obviously he didn't, and if he wants to keep hes original styles, using `!important` will suit his needs.

Comment: Look at his JS Fiddle, he didn't even set the p style... Thus no need to add tag

Comment: He has not set the style for p, not taking about the class that is assigned to the p, that will not override the defaults. All he needs to do is set the p style. If you understand the DOM, you would not what I am talking about in regards to this and the !important tag. You should review that and how it works.

Comment: There's no need for a css reset just to set paragraphs and it could also jumble up his page now that everything else presumably works. Most people don't need a reset and most don't use one.

Answer (score 0):

Every user agent (browser) has its own built in styles. What you see are Chrome's but Firefox has theirs, too, which, in this case, are the same as Chrome's and you can view it in their developer tools.

The way you override them is to just set them to what you want and both browsers will obey.

`p { margin:1em }`

If that's not working for you, something else is affecting this but, unless you show the complete markup, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Comment: What you mean by the complex markup. I am adding the compounded markup.

Comment: Complete, not complex. I didn't see you had a fiddle.